# Make codeigniter behave on $_GET's?

Tags: regex, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I've had a problem with CI handling $_GET and found a way to overcome it.

The question is, **can you see any security problem here?**

I have my urls all ways like

```
/contacts
/company/info
```

And my default controller on CodeIgniter is called ***index***

I can make CI behave with `$_GET` as long  as I follow the  `class/function/default_controller`.

**Both these URL's work:**

```
// class + function + default controller = ok
/class/function/index?var1=this&var2=that

// class + default controller = ok
/class/index?var1=this&var2=that
```

**The thing is I want these to also work**

```
// class without function nor default controller = NOT OK
/class?var1=this&var2=that

// class + function without default controller = NOT OK
/class/function?var1=this&var2=that
```

My solution was a little regex on the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

I'm no expert on regex so, can you see a possible security problem here?

```
/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| MAKE CODEIGNITER BEHAVE ON _GETS!
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| CI doesn't like to play ball with /contacts?a=23 and fails on several ocasions
| This forces the first ? or & to be replaced by /index/ that is the default controller
|
*/
 $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = preg_replace('/\?|\&/', '/index/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. As long as you don't blindly trust the $_GET[] (which you shouldn't anyway), you're good.